# Pouchdb query _id according keyword

Tags: pouchdb

My pouchdb has objects with  with following _id-scheme:

_id: **10_anton_3/1/2017, 10:02:51 AM**

I want to get all documents with *anton*:
What i have tried is:

```
 allDocs({

 include_docs: true,
 attachments: true, 
 startkey : '_anton_\uffff',
 endkey :"_anton_\uffff"})
```

Whats the right way? Can i use startkey and endkey?

**Update:**

I had made use of the search plugin. Therefore i added a property with the name ***name***. That's why I will change my _id scheme. I have hoped I can do this without an external plugin, only with include_docs.

```
database.search({
  query: anton,
  fields: ['name'],
  include_docs: true
}
```

Comment: You don't appear to be calling allDocs properly. You need to pass a callback, or use a promise.

Comment: It looks like your example formatting was messed up by Markdown but I'm not sure how to fix it now so please fix it yourself

Answer (score 0):

If you get rid of the 10 in front of the _id and start the _id with "anton" (I assume the 10 changes between documents), you can directly use all_docs:

```
allDocs({
  include_docs: true,
  attachments: true,
  startkey : 'anton_',
  endkey :"anton_\uffff"
})
```

Hint: also try to convert the dates you use with .toJSON(), so you get lexically sortable strings. Instead of `10_anton_3/1/2017, 10:02:51 AM` you'd use `anton_10_2017-01-03T10:02:51.000Z` as an _id.